# PHP Gallery with lightbox, folder import and descriptions from file names

Tags: php, import, directory, gallery, lightbox

Is there a gallery that have three features:

- displays pictures in a lightbox
- allows to import tens or hundreds of images at once from a folder
- takes descriptions from file names

I have to make it on yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

I've made my own script together with original Lightbox
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
Decided it will be much faster that way:

```
        <?php
            echo str_replace(array('<','>'), array('&lt;','&gt;'),'<table id="galx"><tr>');
            $source_dir = 'images/taken/from/here';
            $mini_dir = 'mini';
            $target_dir = 'imagies/copied/to/there';
            $i=0;

            $images = array_diff(scandir($source_dir), array('..', '.',$mini_dir));
            foreach($images as $image)
            {
                $filename = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $title = mb_strtoupper(trim(str_replace('_',' ',$filename)));
                $s = "<td><a href='$target_dir/$image' data-lightbox='galx' data-title='$title' >"
                        . "<img src='$target_dir/$mini_dir/$filename.jpg' /><br/>"
                        . "$title<a/></td>";  //gallery with titles
                /*$s = "<td><a href='$target_dir/$image' data-lightbox='galx' >"
                        . "<img src='$target_dir/$mini_dir/$filename.jpg' />"
                        . "<a/></td>";*/ //gallery without titles

                if (++$i % 5 == 0)
                    $s .= '</tr><tr>';

                $s = str_replace(array('<','>'), array('&lt;','&gt;'), $s); //comment this line if want to paste it as php code
                echo $s;
            }
            echo str_replace(array('<','>'), array('&lt;','&gt;'),'</tr></table>');
        ?>
```

Some basic css:

```
#galx {
  width: 650px;
}

#galx td {
    text-align: center;
}

#galx a {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin:1px auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I've used FastStone Image Viewer to batch resize images at once and create miniatures. In app just press F3 to open advanced processing tool.

It just won't work with non-english letters on Windows - PHP bug. It still spoils first non-english letter of file name on Linux, so need to prefix '_' in such cases.

Overall good result - i've hided script somewhere on website and in 1,5 hours generated 6 galleries with ~1,5k pictures, and most of the time was consumed by file processing and copying. Not elegant but effective.